# How to reuse the same SVN resource in multiple places

Tags: svn, svn-externals

In SVN I have following folders:

- some_path/solution_A/some_project
- some_path/solution_B

There is some project inside solution_A that I want to reuse in solution_B.
It's not a problem in ClearCase or Perforce where I can map this project to any folder inside solution_B within the workspace. But how can I solve this problem (checkout some_project within solution_B workspace) in SVN without creating duplicates in my SVN tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Read about [SVN Externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html)
- Map `some_path/solution_A/some_project` as target of external folder definition in `some_path/solution_B`: you'll see nothing (except new commit appeared) changed in repository for solution_B, but when you'll checkout solution_B with externals into WC (or update existing WC) - you'll get new folder in tree. identical to `solution_A/some_project`

Comment: Thank you. It works. Here is the useful link how to do this with minimal efforts: https://help.cloudforge.com/entries/22483742-Setting-up-svn-externals